# Display image makes page blank React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

When I add this line off code, instead of showing the image, my page gets blank. How can I fix this?

```
<img>
   src={"https://media1.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2019_21/2870431/190524-classic-american-cheeseburger-ew-207p_d9270c5c545b30ea094084c7f2342eb4.jpg"}  alt={''}
</img>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

src is not the child component of  tag. src is a attribute of  tag.

```
<img src={"https://media1.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2019_21/2870431/190524-classic-american-cheeseburger-ew-207p_d9270c5c545b30ea094084c7f2342eb4.jpg"}  alt={''}
```

/>

check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp for details.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the img tag incorrectly, Please update it as :

```
<img src={'https://media1.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2019_21/2870431/190524-classic-american-cheeseburger-ew-207p_d9270c5c545b30ea094084c7f2342eb4.jpg'} />
```

Also, recheck the image link as it shows unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

img is self closing tag and it's required the src attribute. correct way to use img tag is:

```
<img src={"https://media1.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2019_21/2870431/190524-classic-american-cheeseburger-ew-207p_d9270c5c545b30ea094084c7f2342eb4.jpg"} />
```

check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img for more information